# Change value in found item

Tags: rust

I'm trying to find and change a specific item in an iterator like this:

```rust
struct ItemType {
    name: &'static str,
    value: i32
}

struct OuterType {
    list: Vec<ItemType>
}

impl OuterType {
    pub fn setByName(
        self: &mut Self,
        name: &str
    ) -> Result<(), String> {

        match self.list.iter().find(|item| item.name == name) {
            Some(item_found) => {
                item_found.value = 1;
            },
            None => {
                return Err(format!("unrecognized item name (was \"{}\")", name));
            }
        }

        Ok(())
    }
}
```

But this does not compile because of several reasons, some of which:

- no `Copy` trait (don't want to change a copy, I want to change the item in-place);
- not borrowed, add `&` (does not help);
- not mutable, add `mut` (does not help);
- cannot assign to `item_found.value` which is behind a `&`;
- at some point it says `&` can **PROBABLY** be removed... (WHAT?);
- those errors are cyclic, I'm ping-pong-ing between them with no exit.

I've also tried to `.find(|&item| ...)`.

What is going on? Don't I get to own the value returned by `find()`? And how am I supposed to change `item_found.value`? It's just an integer in a struct which is one of several in a vector I get the iterator for.

Comment: What is the type of `iterator`? That's a very confusing set of errors you've got. At one point, you say it's not borrowed, and then two bullets down you tell us it's behind a `&`. Which is it?

Comment: What is `iterator`? Because *that* is what determines whether you can mutate a value or not

Comment: @SilvioMayolo as I change the code by following the error message hints I slip from one error to another. That's why there are different errors. In one version it says "not borrowed, add &", then it says "add mut", then "probably remove &" and so on... There's clearly an underlying problem I can't solve by just retouching code as indicated in error messages.

Comment: @kmdreko I'll post a more complete version of the code in minute.

Comment: Hint: `iter()` returns an immutable iterator. On the other hand, there is also `iter_mut()`.

Comment: Unrelated note, but you can do without a match entirely, thanks to a few tricks. See https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=714b105bfef33f4878978c5da7acc388 for a demonstration.

Comment: @SirDarius thanks I'll do it exactly that way! And..... the snake_case aaarghgh I'm struggling getting used to it! thanks for correcting that, too!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `iter_mut` instead of `iter` when you need to mutate the value:

```rust
match self.list.iter_mut().find(...) {...}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=de859401ec75c0495de26a1f417dca5a)

Comment: That actually worked! I'm rather impressed by rust about how painstakingly finicky it is! There's no way to fool it, but there's always a way to fool oneself :D